# Best practice for Angular4 services calling APIs .Net Core

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core

I am using the hybrid template of Angular and .Net Core 2.0.

In my component page, a method lists people based on some criteria and it works just fine. Each person, however, has a department ID that I would like to get their department name from another API method.

I could create a SQL view which lists all info in it but I rather to call methods that return all queries I need. So in my component page I want to call create a service that uses      {{personDeptId}}       to return their department name.

```
    [HttpGet("[action]/{login?}")]
    public async Task<String> getUserDeprtString(String login)
    {...
    }
```

The above method returns the department name successfully. My issue is in the implementation at the front-side.

I created a service, Dataservice:

```
getPersonDepart(login: String): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/User/getUserDeprtString/' + login).map(this.extractData)
        .do(data => console.log('getProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and in the component:

```
 getName(name: String) {
   return this.dataService.getPersonDepart(name); }
```

and in component page:

```
 {{getPersonDepart(personDeptId)}}
```

and it always return 500 Error

Any suggestion?

---

Update1: 
the error is gone now. I had to mention the service in the component providers. I can see now the api returns the correct response. However, it goes to an infinite loop (calling the methods non-stop!) and I am not sure why. Any idea?

Comment: 500 means internal server error. can you debut from your controller? I have angular4 client and asp.net web api backend and use swashbuckle to generate the typescript client for the client

Comment: When I go to the api URL , it returns the correct response but when I use it within my component page it gives that error.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the controller function. then you can see where your code fails

Comment: and is this [action] required? I have `[HttpGet("id")]
        public string Get(string id)`

Comment: the error is gone now. I had to mention the service in the component providers. I can see now the api returns the correct response. However, it goes to an infinite loop (calling the methods non-stop!) and I am not sure why. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

The infinite loop is likely caused by this:

```
{{getPersonDepart(personDeptId)}}
```

You're asking Angular to invoke `getPersonDepart` when it renders the component. Once this completes, Angular will render the component once again, which will cause Angular to run `getPersonDepart` again, which will cause the rendering to happen again, etc, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. But how to get it fixed? Any suggestion?

Comment: I created a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587847/infinite-loop-within-angular-component) I hope the question is clear this time

Answer (score 0):

check if the "route" include in anyway "api". e.g.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts(){..}
}
```

Comment: My issue in the Angular component. Calling the api method works fine.